# .Net Remoting Question

Tags: c#-2.0, .net-remoting

My understanding of .Net Remoting is limited (and probably imperfect), so please bear with me.

I've created a service that is hosting a singleton remoted object.  It appears that the remoted object doesn't exist until a client attaches to the remoted object.  Is this true?  If so, how can I create an instance of the object in the service?

Thanks
Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you answer!
Actually, I found a way to get what I wanted.  The key is that the object that is being hosted for remoting (as a singleton) needs to be a thin wrapper for an actual singleton object (as in Singleton<>).  This way the base object will be created no matter what and the remotely hosted object will then be a wrapper for the internal singleton.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that there is no way to do this without calling a method on the object - It's just how server activation works.

You don't indicate why you need to do this, but I'd guess it is because the initialization of the singleton takes a while. Perhaps you could factor off the initialization into another class which is loaded at application startup, and this would reduce the singleon startup costs.